# Entity Framework and LINQ left join and include on same table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq, entity-framework

I have the following class structure for my Users and the permissions they're in for the different companies they may be associated to:

```
public class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public List<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }
    public Company DefaultCompany { get; set; }
}

public class Permission
{
    public User User { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }
    public int PermissionLevel { get; set; }
}

public class Company
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

This results in three SQL tables.  There is a FK between Permission.User_Id > User.Id and Permission.Company_Id > Company.Id.  There is no *explicit* relationship (ie. FK) between User.DefaultCompany and the Company table.  This is on purpose due to a legacy choice in our database schema.

I also have a database repository method that grabs a user by it's Id, and includes the full Company record:

```
public User GetById(Guid Id)
{
    return (from r in this.Context.Users.Include("Permissions.Company")
        where r.Id == Id
        select r)
        .SingleOrDefault();
}
```

This works fine, but it doesn't set the `DefaultCompany` property.  So I tried setting that by changing this method to the following.  It's worth pointing out that the Company record that represents the DefaultCompany shares the same ID value as the User.

```
public User GetById(Guid Id)
{
    return (from r in this.Context.Users.Include("Permissions.Company")
            where r.Id == Id
            join c in this.Context.Companies on r.Id equals c.Id into companies
            from company in companies.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new { User = r, Company = company })
            .ToList()
            .Select(p => { p.User.DefaultCompany = p.Company; return p.User; })
            .SingleOrDefault();
}
```

And this does, in fact, set the `DefaultCompany` but  it has the side effect of *not* selecting the `Permissions` list.  I can do this all as two separate operations, as in the following code, but I'd rather not hit the database twice if I don't have to.

```
public User GetById(Guid Id)
{
    var u = (from r in this.Context.Users.Include("Permissions.Company")
            where r.Id == Id
            select r)
            .SingleOrDefault();

    u.DefaultCompany = (from r in this.Context.Companies where r.Id == u.Id select r).SingleOrDefault();

    return u;
}
```

Is there another way to accomplish this?

Edit: explaining resulting SQL data model and additional example.

Comment: It's very hard to understand your DB model. Can you explain more clearly which are the relations between entities, or even show an schema? Which is the key for Permission? I think your porblem comes from the model itself, and not from the way you're making your queries.

Comment: @JotaBe I've edited my question.  Apologies for it being unclear -- the data model is much more complex and legacy than I've documented here, but I'm trying to grasp the underlying difference between the two queries and why adding the join causes the Permission list to not be populated.

Comment: Now it's much more clear. No reason to apologize: but if the question is not clear you're the one who loses the chance to get an answer :). Try something, and let me know if it works to add it as answer (with extra explanations). Project the `r.Permissions.Company` / `p.User.Permissions.Company` in your anonymous type projections (inside your new {})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible solutions for this problem.

The cleanest is to use the Fluent API to indicate the model that there is a 1 to 1 relation between User and Company.

Override the `OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)` method of your context.

Inside it, configure the 1 ro 1 relation like this:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
             .HasOptional(u => u.DefaultCompany)
             .WithRequired();
```

*NOTE: with this configuration there is a relationship of 1 user to 0 or 1 default companies (note the Optional in `HasOptional`). And the default company must have a User on the other side. When a 1 to 1 (or 1 to 0..1) relation is configured, EF will automatically use the PK of the related tables to create the relation between them. You can fine tune the relation using other Fluent API functions*

After doing so, you can include the `DefaultCompany` using `Include()`:

```
User user = ctx.Users
               .Include(u => u.DefaultCompany)
               .SingleOrDefault(u => u.Id == userId);
```

The other, more ugly solution, is to use your second query and include the missing permissions in the projection, to force EF to recover them from the DB.

```
// ...
select new { User = r, Company = company, Companies = r.Permissions } 
// ...
```

Comment: Using projection seemed to work, but after that I started getting some ugly errors when saving records (`A relationship from the 'Permission_User' AssociationSet is in the 'Deleted' state. Given multiplicity constraints, a corresponding 'Permission_User_Source' must also in the 'Deleted' state.`) so I'm not sure what to do there.  I'll try the Fluent API method, but I'm not sure I understand how your suggestion defines the implicit relationship between User.Id and Company.Id.  Also, if this was unclear, in my model, a DefaultCompany may not exist for every user.

Comment: I've tried to explain why the id's of both tables are chosen to create the relationship. Although you didn't tell that the default company was optional, I guessed it :). As to the other failure, it must be a problem with change tracking and relation fixup when you load collections in a "non-standard" way. (I should have to analyze it carefully, but have no time.  I thought you was going only to use it for reading).